# Java regular expression for repeated letters

Tags: java, regex

I can't find a regex that matches repeated letters. My problem is that I want to use regex to filter out spam-mails, for example, I want to use regex to detect "spam" and "viagra" in these strings :
"xxxSpAmyyy",
"xxxSPAMyyy",
"xxxvI a Gr AA yyy",
"xxxV iiA  gR  a   xxx"

Do You have any suggestions how I do that in a good way?

Comment: Did you try anything so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ignores the case, and it takes them whether they are one next to another, or there are other characters in between them

```
"(?i).{0,}v.{0,}i.{0,}a.{0,}g.{0,}r.{0,}a.{0,}"
```

If you know how many characters can be between the letters, you can enter `.{0,max_distance}` instead of `.{0,}`

UPDATE:

It works even for duplicates, as i have tried it:

```
    String str = "xxxV iiA gR a xxx";

    if(str.matches("(?i).{0,}v.{0,}i.{0,}a.{0,}g.{0,}r.{0,}a.{0,}")){
        System.out.println("Yes");
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("No");
    }
```

This prints `Yes`

Comment: I have tried this, it does not work when there are duplicates of one or more letters in the string, as the last string has ("ii"). But it's the best suggestion so far.

Comment: Yes, sorry. My misstake was that I tried with max_distance = 5, it was too small, when max_distnce > 5 it works! I thought it was distans between "v" and "i" for example and not the length of the word.

Answer (score 0):

Like searching this?

```
"v.{0,3}i.{0,3}a.{0,3}g.{0,3}r.{0,3}a"
```

See [Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#columnAtPoint%28java.awt.Point%29)

---

***Code:***

This leaves space for 0 to 3 characters between characters. I did not compile the following,
but it "should work."

```
String[] strings = new String[] { ""xxxV iiA gR a xxx"" };
final Pattern spamPattern = makePattern("viagra");
for (String s : strings) {
    boolean isSpam = spamPattern.matcher(s).find();
    if (isSpam) {
        System.out.println("Spam: " + s);
    }
}
...
Pattern makePattern(String cusWord) {
    cusWord = cusWord.toLowerCase();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("(?i)"); // Case-insensitive setting.
    for (int i = 0; i < cusWord.length(); ) {
        int cp = cusWord.codePointAt(i);
        i += Character.charCount(cp);
        if ('o' == cp) {
            sb.append("[o0]");
        } else if ('l' == cp) {
            sb.append("[l1]");
        } else {
            sb.appendCodePoint(cp);
        }
        sb.append(".{0,3}"); // 0 - 3 occurrences of any char.
    }
    return Pattern.compile(sb.toString());
}
```

Comment: I have tried this, it does not work when there are duplicates of one or more letters in the string, as the last string has ("ii").

Comment: The makePattern-method is great! I have tried it and it works fine, even on more advanced strings like "afdkV i AA ggggxRrR aAqwofv". But I do not understand the "0-3 occurrences" shouldn't it be 1-3?

Comment: "Viagra" so matches as 0 other characters are in between.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you're on wrong way. Filtering of spam is closely related to machine learning. I'd suggest you to read about **[Bayesian spam filtering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_spam_filtering)**.

If you suppose, that you'll get spam mails with misspelled words (and other kind of garbage) - I'd suggest to use filtering based not on entire words, but on **[n-grams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-gram#n-grams_for_approximate_matching)**.

Comment: It is just an example, I need the regex to match these type of text, not neccessary for spam-filer, but thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try any regex?

Something like `\w*[sSpPaAmM]+\w*` should do the trick

You can test your RE on this site : http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html

Comment: I have tried this now, it does not work when there are duplicates of one or more letters in the string, as the last string has ("ii"), same problem that the other syntax had, that Mr. Eggen suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [positive look-aheads](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

```
(?=.*v)(?=.*i)(?=.*a)(?=.*g)(?=.*r)(?=.*a).*
```

Edit:

```
(?=.*v.*i.*a.*g.*r.*a.*).*
```

Comment: Do you have an example of a non-matched string?